# Why does the rectangle disappear when loading \usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Probability}
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\only<2>{\node[right=10,gray,draw,fill=white,text width=130,align=left] at (5,0) {Update the probability $s_n$};}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I need to load `\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}`. When I do, the command `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\only<2>{\node[right=10,gray,draw,fill=white,text width=130,align=left] at (5,0) {Update the probability $s_n$};}}` will not have any effect. In other words, the rectangle disappears after loading the package. Do you have any idea why?

Before loading the package I get:

[image]

But after loading the package I get:

[image]

Comment: did you compile twice? Remove the overlay, remember picture part and try again

Comment: Yes, more than twice. The problem is with `automata` I think.

Comment: I don't think so. That doesn't load any related parts

Comment: Change `right=10` to `right=10pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking @Benjamin's comment about `right=10pt` into accout, the code needs to be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{%
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif} %[serif] is deprecated
}%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Probability}
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\only<2>{\node[right=10pt,gray,draw,fill=white,text width=130,align=left] at (5,0) {Update the probability $s_n$};}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Also the `serif`-option is deprecated, hence the code is using the more appropriate `\usefonttheme{serif}`.